# const pointer to const pointer to const data

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I got a lot of const here. So i need to know which ones are really needed.

I need to use a pointer to a pointer where the pointer is const and the data pointed to is const.
Does the following make sense?

```
const int a=5;
const int* const pi=&a;
const int* const * const ppi=&pi;  // three const here? correct?
```

Well it compiles without warning, and make sense to me, as
ppi is const
*ppi is const
and **ppi is const

I need to use ppi and want as much const as possible, as i am programming for an micro controller and want the data to go to flash.
I know there are are ways to force data to go to flash but i'd prefer the linker to do so automatically.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Is that the question?

Comment: It is important to note that marking things as `const` won't necessarily put them in the flash memory of your microcontroller.

Comment: What kind of MCU it is? At least some MCUs (at least AVR8) has a very special syntax to tell "it should go to Flash".

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers.
I know there are linker specific ways to tell the data belongs to flash, but i wont it to be placed there automatically if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is OK, since you want as much const-ness as possible. However, this is going to affect the future use of these data. I am not sure however if this will make the linker to put your data in flash memory, so read this question: [ARM C++ - how to put const members in flash memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712617/arm-c-how-to-put-const-members-in-flash-memory).